# PLSQL Procedure to iterate through SELECT statement and extract columns values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have the below query (results attached in screenshot):

```
SELECT make, year, color, count(*) 
FROM cars
GROUPY BY make, year, color
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

[image: 1]

I want to iterate through the resulting table and produce sub queries for the criteria in each row (examples below). I hope to then use these sub queries to make a single table with samples results that meet the criteria of each of the rows from the original table.

This may seem like an odd or unnecessary request, but this is a simplified example for readability purposes. This is the approach I want to take for my own reasoning, as I want a solution that I can come back to and alter for future use and for different variations of queries.

```
SELECT * from cars 
WHERE make = 'Jeep'
AND  year = '2019'
AND color = 'Black';


SELECT * from cars 
WHERE make = 'Ford'
AND year = '2018'
AND color = 'Red';
```

Comment: your first query will give you an error

Comment: You do not need any subquery or iteration, use convenient way: join both the tables on the matching columns. Check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) for syntax and [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you merely want to pick sample data from the table, e.g. one row per make, year and color? This can be done with a rather simple query. Your first query lacks a `GROUP BY` clause and is hence invalid. If you add that clause you will get the counts. But you don't seem to want to use the counts. Then you say you want to build single queries, but in the end it sounds like this is not what you are really after either. What I am saying is: Please describe what you want to finally achieve rather than asking things that are probably irrelevant for this.

Comment: _"I have the below query (results attached in screenshot):"_   No, you do not. That query will not pass the parse phase.  Please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

you can prepare the strings like so and run them later

```
select 'select * from cars where make = ''' || make || ''' and year = ''' || year || ''' and color = ''' || color || ''';' 
from cars
```